# How to make one core execute a function and broadcast the resulting string to other cores using mpi4py?

Tags: python, python-3.x, mpi, mpi4py

I am using mpi4py to parallelize my code. There is one function which I want only one core to execute. Until then, I want other processors to wait. I tried to implement this functionality using the following snippet of code:

```
from mpi4py import MPI

class PARALLELIZE:
    rank = -1
    comm = None
    size = -1

    def __init__(self):

        self.comm = MPI.COMM_WORLD
        self.rank = self.comm.Get_rank()
        self.size = self.comm.Get_size()

    def get_name(self):

        return "abc.pdb"

    def perform_single_operation(self, fun):

        ret_value = ""
        if self.rank == 0:
            ret_value = fun()

        # broadcast the ret_val to other ranks
        ret_value = self.comm.bcast(ret_value, root=0)
        return ret_value
```

I call this method using the following:

```
if __name__ == "main":

    p = PARALLELIZE()
    p.perform_single_operation(p.get_name)
```

If I run this code with 3 cores. I face several issues:
1. core 0 is not being reached first
2. cores 1 and 2 send out a bool value from perform_single_operation
3. only root 0 continues execution. Other cores cannot produce meaningful results since they don't have valid name

All I want this functionality to do is, get the name based on some computation and broadcast it to others so that all the cores can proceed with the same data. I am unable to get it to work. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I have tried your code (juste removed the if __ name __ == "main": because __ name __ contains __ main __ for me, i use python 2.7)  and it seems nothing is wrong with it (on my platform). I added a timer time.sleep(1.0) after if self.rank == 0: to force core 0 to not be the first to call bcast all works well. Have you tried C or C++ examples to check nothing is wrong with your MPI setup ?

Comment: Found any solution?